# Slow website load with CNAME, fast when using IP

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind

I setup two DNS servers on my network: ns1.byte-werx.com && ns2.byte-werx.com

I can ping the DNS servers and get a fairly good response time, when I dig them I also get a fairly reasonable response, but any website I filter through them is painfully slow (an upwards of 20+ seconds) -- verifiable by performing a tracert or attempting to access the URL in a browser.

The DNS servers are running CentOS 6.3 and BIND9 with 500MB of memory (I figure that should be more than enough?). I have a reverse look-up zone (1.168.192) along with two website zones (www.byte-werx.com and www.stayhomedental.com)

If I access the websites using their IP the page loads nearly instantly so I do not believe the issue is with the hosting server, but that is running Ubuntu Server 12.04 and Apache2 with 12GB memory.

Any thoughts? I do not have the named.conf file in front of me but I can edit this post to include it if you feel it would be useful.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: What do you mean by "filter through them"?

Comment: Sorry, I know that is the wrong term.. I am a software engineer, not a network guy alas. So in this case, lets assume "Filter through" means accessing that DNS server to attempt to do a look-up (Does that make more sense?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ns2.byte-werx.com** gave me a SERVFAIL when looking up `www.byte-werx.com`, `byte-werx.com`, `stayhomedental.com` and `www.stayhomedental.com`.

**ns1.byte-werx.com** worked fine for all of those domains.

IntoDNS has lots of good information:

1. http://www.intodns.com/byte-werx.com
2. http://www.intodns.com/stayhomedental.com

---

In addition, `www.byte-werx.com` is not a CNAME and `byte-werx.com` has two A records, one of which times out on port 80.  The same is true for `www.stayhomedental.com` and `stayhomedental.com` respectively.